# VB code not calculating

Tags: vb.net

For some reason when I run this it only ever calculates to 0
Where am I going wrong? :(
The user has 3 input boxes to place values. From there those values should be calculating. It only ever equals a value of 0. I get no errors

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnCal_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCal.Click

Dim dblPacA, dblPacB, dblPacC, dblAnswerA, dblAnswerB, dblAnswerC, dblGrandTotal As Double
Dim dblAnswerA1, dblAnswerB1, dblAnswerC1 As Double

'Packages Retail
Dim dblPACA_FACTOR As Double = 99
Dim dblPACB_FACTOR As Double = 199
Dim dblPACC_FACTOR As Double = 299

'Rate of each range
Dim dblTENNINE_FACTOR As Double = 0.8
Dim dblTWONINE_FACTOR As Double = 0.7
Dim dblFIVENINE_FACTOR As Double = 0.6
Dim dblONETEN_FACTOR As Double = 0.5

Try
'important calculate
dblAnswerA1 = dblPacA * dblPACA_FACTOR
dblAnswerB1 = dblPacB * dblPACB_FACTOR
dblAnswerC1 = dblPacC * dblPACC_FACTOR



dblPacA = CDbl(txtPacA.Text)
dblPacB = CDbl(txtPacB.Text)
dblPacC = CDbl(txtPacC.Text)

dblGrandTotal = dblAnswerA + dblAnswerB + dblAnswerC
lblGrandTotal.Text = "Gran Total:" & (dblGrandTotal.ToString("c"))
'lblAnswer.Text = dblAnswer.ToString
'lblAnswer.Text = "PackageA:" & dblAnswerA _
' & "PackageB:" & dblAnswerB & "PackageC:" _
'& dblAnswerC & "GrandTotal:" & dblGrandTotal
Catch
End Try

If dblPacA >= 0 Then
If dblPacA < 10 Then
dblAnswerA = dblAnswerA1
lblAnswerA.Text = "PackageA:" & dblAnswerA.ToString("c")
ElseIf dblPacA >= 10 And dblPacA < 20 Then
dblAnswerA = dblAnswerA1 * dblTENNINE_FACTOR
lblAnswerA.Text = "PackageA:" & (dblAnswerA.ToString("c"))
ElseIf dblPacA >= 20 And dblPacA < 50 Then
dblAnswerA = dblAnswerA1 * dblTWONINE_FACTOR
lblAnswerA.Text = "PackageA:" & dblAnswerA.ToString("c")
ElseIf dblPacA >= 50 And dblPacA < 100 Then
dblAnswerA = dblAnswerA1 * dblFIVENINE_FACTOR
lblAnswerA.Text = "PackageA:" & dblAnswerA.ToString("c")
ElseIf dblAnswerA >= 100 Then
dblAnswerA = dblAnswerA1 * dblONETEN_FACTOR
lblAnswerA.Text = "PackageA:" & dblAnswerA.ToString("c")
End If
Else
MessageBox.Show("txtPacA must be greater than or equal to 0", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
End If

If dblPacB >= 0 Then
If dblPacB >= 10 And dblPacB <= 19 Then
dblAnswerB = dblAnswerB1 * dblTENNINE_FACTOR
lblAnswerB.Text = "PackageB:" & dblAnswerB.ToString("c")
ElseIf dblPacB >= 20 And dblPacB <= 49 Then
dblAnswerB = dblAnswerB1 * dblTWONINE_FACTOR
lblAnswerB.Text = "PackageB:" & dblAnswerB.ToString("c")
ElseIf dblPacB >= 50 And dblPacB <= 99 Then
dblAnswerB = dblAnswerB1 * dblFIVENINE_FACTOR
lblAnswerB.Text = "PackageB:" & dblAnswerB.ToString("c")
Else
dblAnswerB = dblAnswerB * dblONETEN_FACTOR
lblAnswerB.Text = "PackageB:" & dblAnswerB.ToString("c")
End If
Else
MessageBox.Show("txtPacB must be greater than or equal to 0", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
End If

If dblPacC >= 0 Then
If dblPacC >= 10 And dblPacC <= 19 Then
dblAnswerC = dblAnswerC1 * dblTENNINE_FACTOR
lblAnswerC.Text = "PackageC:" & dblAnswerC.ToString("c")
ElseIf dblPacC >= 20 And dblPacA <= 49 Then
dblAnswerC = dblAnswerC1 * dblTWONINE_FACTOR
lblAnswerC.Text = "PackageC:" & dblAnswerC.ToString("c")
ElseIf dblPacC >= 50 And dblPacC <= 99 Then
dblAnswerC = dblAnswerC1 * dblFIVENINE_FACTOR
lblAnswerC.Text = "PackageC:" & dblAnswerC.ToString("c")
Else
dblAnswerC = dblAnswerC1 * dblONETEN_FACTOR
lblAnswerC.Text = "PackageC:" & dblAnswerC.ToString("c")
End If
Else
MessageBox.Show("txtPacC must be greater than or equal to 0", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Step through it in the debugger and look at the values.

Comment: what does `ToString("c")` do in vb?

Comment: i see that you are using Hungarian notation.. you should read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Comment: converts the string into currency format mkoryak

Comment: Try to debug..you can see the answer of your problem..

Comment: is indentation not used in vb?

Answer (score 1):

```
dblAnswerA1 = dblPacA * dblPACA_FACTOR
```

where is dblPacA 's value set? its not. its 0